# Expectation of maximum number of non-overlapping random intervals inside $[0,1]$ out of $n$ intervals

Tags: probability, statistics

Choose two random numbers from $[0,1]$ and let them be the endpoints of a random interval. Repeat this independently for $n$ times to get $n$ random subintervals (denoted as $U_1,\dots,U_n$).

Let $T_n = \max\{|S|: S\subset\{U_1,\dots,U_n\}, U_i\cap U_j=\emptyset \mbox{ for any }U_i\not =U_j\in S\}$, where $|S|$denote the number of intervals in $S$.

I'm wondering what is the expectation of $T_n$? Or how fast does the expectation of $T_n$ increase with $n$? ( is it $O(n)$, $O(\sqrt{n})$ or $O(\log n)$?)

Comment: Could you report the estimated expectation for some values of $n$?

Answer (score 2):

Simulation suggests  the expectation grows slightly faster than $\sqrt{n}$, though perhaps not enough faster to avoid being $O(\sqrt{n})$.

Using R and looking at $n=1,2,\ldots,100$ with $10\,000$ simulations each:

```
numbernonoverlapping <- function(n){
   intervals <- matrix(runif(2*n), ncol=2, nrow=n)
   remaining <- matrix(ncol=2, nrow=n)
   remaining[,1] <- ifelse(intervals[,1] < intervals[,2], 
                           intervals[,1], intervals[,2])
   remaining[,2] <- intervals[,1] + intervals[,2] - remaining[,1]
   countintervals <- 0
   while(nrow(remaining) > 0){ 
     lowestupper <- min(remaining[,2])
     whichlowestupper <- min(which(remaining[,2] == lowestupper))
     remaining <- matrix(
         remaining[remaining[,1] > remaining[whichlowestupper,2],], ncol=2)
     countintervals <- countintervals +1  
     }
   return(countintervals)
   }

set.seed(2024)
maxn <- 100
simspern <- 10000
experimental <- numeric(maxn)
for (n in 1:maxn){
  experimental[n] <- mean(replicate(simspern, numbernonoverlapping(n)))
  }
n <- 1:maxn
plot(n,experimental)
curve(sqrt(x), from=1, to=maxn, add=TRUE)
```

you get the experimental means (including simulation noise) slightly above $\sqrt{n}$ when $n>6$.

[image: simulated expectations compared to sqrt(n)]

Dividing the experimental means by $\sqrt{n}$ gives the following chart (with the simulation noise more obvious); reassuringly, the value of about $0.94$ when $n=2$ corresponds to the theoretical $\frac{4/3}{\sqrt{2}}$ since the probability of two intervals not overlapping is $\frac13$.

```
plot(n, experimental/sqrt(n))
```

[image]

---

With some further thought, I think I can provide a recursion for $\mathbb E[T_n]$, starting with the trivial $T_0=0$ and $T_1=1$:

$$\mathbb E[T_n]=\dfrac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{k\, (2n-k-1)!}{2^{n-k}\,(n-k)!}(1+\mathbb E[T_{n-k}])}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{k\, (2n-k-1)!}{2^{n-k}\,(n-k)!}} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{n-1 \choose k-1}{2n-1 \choose k}2^{k-1}(1+\mathbb E[T_{n-k}])$$ where the denominator sum is the so-called double factorial $(2n-1)!!=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n \, n!}$.  It might be possible to use this to show $O(\sqrt{n})$.

For $n=1,2,3,4,5,6$ this gives $\mathbb E[T_n] = 1,\frac{4}{3},\frac{25}{15},\frac{206}{105},\frac{2101}{945},\frac{25564}{10395}$ and my earlier simulations were close to these.

For $n=10000$ it gives $\mathbb E[T_{10000}]\approx 112.4759$, which is $1.124759$ times $\sqrt{10000}$.

Extrapolating, I doubt $\mathbb E[T_n]$ ever exceeds $1.1284 \sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 2):

I can prove that
$$
-\tfrac12+\sqrt{n}\le \newcommand\E{\mathbb E}\E T_n\le e\sqrt{n/2}+O(1)
$$
So, the growth rate of $\E T_n$ is $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$.

##### Upper bound

Let $t\in \mathbb N$. Using the union bound, we have
$$
\newcommand\P{\mathbb P} \P(T_n\ge t)\le \binom{n}t\frac{2^t\cdot t!}{(2t)!}
$$
Indeed, in order for $T_n\ge t$ to occur, there needs to exist $t$ particular intervals which do not overlap. There are $\binom nt$ selections of $t$ intervals. For each of these, the probability they do not overlap is $2^t\cdot t!/(2t)!$. This is because each of the $(2t)!$ ordering of the $2t$ endpoints are equally likely, but there are only $2^t\cdot t!$ successful orderings. Now, using the inequalities $\binom nt\le n^t/t!$ and $(2t)!\ge (2t)^{2t}\cdot e^{-t}$, the above becomes
$$
\P(T_n\ge t)\le \left(\frac{e\sqrt{n/2}}{t}\right)^{2t}
$$
Now, let $t=e\sqrt{n/2}+m$, for some $m\in \mathbb N$. We see that
$$
\begin{align}
\P\left(T_n\ge e\sqrt{n/2}+m\right)
&\le  \left(\frac{e\sqrt{n/2}}{e\sqrt{n/2}+m}\right)^{2\left(e\sqrt{n/2}+m\right)}
\\& = \left(1 + \frac{-m}{m+e\sqrt{n/2}}\right)^{2\left(e\sqrt{n/2}+m\right)}
\\&\le e^{-2m}
\end{align}
$$
The last inequality uses the fact that $(1+x/n)^n\le e^x$, valid when $|x|\le n$. The above shows that $P(T_n\ge t)$ drops off exponentially quickly as $t$ increases past $e\sqrt{n/2}$. Combined with the equation $\E T_n=\sum_{t\ge 1}P(T_n\ge t)$, this leads to a quick proof that $\E T_n\le e\sqrt{n/2}+O(1)$.

##### Lower bound

I claim that, when $n\ge 1$,
$$
\mathbb E[T_{n+1}\mid T_n] \ge T_n+\frac1{2T_n+1}
$$
To prove the above, it suffices to prove that whenever there exists $T_n$ disjoint intervals among $U_1,\dots,U_n$, then the next interval $U_{n+1}$ can be added to this set with probability at least $1/(2T_n)$.

Call the two endpoints of $U_{n+1}$ $a$ and $b$. There are $T_n$ intervals, with $2T_n$ endpoints, dividing the unit interval into $2T_n+1$ sections. In order to succeed, the point $a$ needs to avoid the interiors of the $T_n$ intervals, leaving $T_n+1$ sections where $a$ can land. These are equally likely, so the probability that $a$ is not in a previous interval is $(T_n+1)/(2T_n+1)$. Conditional on $a$, we have $2T_n+2$ sections of the line where $b$ can land. We have only succeeded if $b$ lands in one of the $2$ subsections which neighbors $a$. Putting this altogether, the probability we can add $U_{n+1}$ to the collection of disjoint intervals is
$$
\frac{T_n+1}{2T_n+1}\cdot \frac{2}{2T_n+2}= \frac1{2T_n+1},
$$
as claimed.

This inequality leads to a proof by induction that $\E T_n\ge -\tfrac12+\sqrt n$ for all $n\ge 1$.
$$
\begin{align}
\E T_{n+1}
  &\stackrel1= \E[\E[T_{n+1}\mid T_n]]
\\&\ge \E\left[T_n+ \frac1{2T_n+1}\right]
\\&= \E\,T_n+ \E\left[\frac1{2T_n+1}\right]
\\&\stackrel2\ge \E\,T_n+ \frac1{2\cdot \E T_n + 1}
\\&\stackrel3\ge (-\tfrac12+\sqrt{n})+\frac1{2\cdot (-\tfrac12+\sqrt{n})+1}
\\&\ge -\tfrac12+\sqrt{n+1}.
\end{align}
$$
Explanations:

1. This is the tower property of conditional expectation. Equivalently, this is the law of total expectation, with respect to the possible values of $T_n$.
2. Jensen's inequality.
3. Here, I use the inductive hypothesis, combined with the fact that the function $f(x)=x+\frac1{2x+1}$ is increasing on the interval $[0.5,\infty)$.